# Is Chrome just a UIWebView? Why does my web browser is not as fast as chrome? on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, uiwebview, browser

I've a couple of questions and I can't find answers anywhere.

1- Does Google Chrome use `UIWebView` for rendering and showing web pages?

2- If yes (someone says chrome is just a `UIWebView`) why my web browser (I created a simple web browser with `UIWebView`) is not as fast (and stable) as Google Chrome. What is difference? What do they add for improving app performance?

3- When I open 10 tabs in chrome, does that mean there are 10 different `UIWebView` in background?

Comment: 1- Yes, Google Chrome uses UIWebView due to Apple's rules. 
3- Probably yes, how else can be done?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how an app works. There is no way to know for sure how a developer decided to solve a problem unless someone with access to the source code comes in and answers the question.  Also, one question per question.

Comment: @Simon Goldeen then I change my question, how can I improve my simple web browser's performance? I use UIWebView and I can't modify anything in my browser engine?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is faster because of their network layer implementation which does many optimisations/caching etc. E.g. DNS pre-resolve, TCP pre-connect,Resource prefetching, Page prerendering etc

Read about it more from [here](http://www.igvita.com/posa/high-performance-networking-in-google-chrome/#mobile)